# Show that $F(x)=\int_0^x f(t)\ dt.$ is differentiable. if $f(x)=\begin{cases} \cos(1/x) & x\neq 0\\ 0 & x=0\end{cases}.$ bounded,continuous except x=0

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, derivatives, trigonometry

The function

$f(x)=\begin{cases} \cos(1/x) & x\neq 0\\ 0 & x=0\end{cases}.$

is bounded, and is continuous except at 0. Hence it is integrable. Show that the function

$F(x)=\int_0^x f(t)\ dt.$

is differentiable.

I have tried proving that by using the derivative of the function $g(x)=\begin{cases} x^2\sin(1/x) & x\neq 0\\ 0 & x=0\end{cases}$

I took the derivative and got $g'(x)=2x\sin(1/x)-cos(1/x)$, and I couldn't proceed from there.

Comment: This looks very much like a problem from Spivak's *Calculus*. Doesn't the formula for $g'(x)$ relate to $f(x)$?

Comment: Can you tell me what is the problems number? do you mean by $f(x)=2x\sin(1/x)-g'(x)$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nice approach. The function$$\begin{array}{rccc}h\colon&\Bbb R&\longrightarrow&\Bbb R\\&x&\mapsto&\begin{cases}x\sin\left(\frac1x\right)&\text{ if }x\ne0\\0&\text{ if }x=0\end{cases}\end{array}$$is continuous, and therefore integrable on any interval $[a,b]$. And $f=2h-g'$. Therefore\begin{align}F(x)&=\int_0^xf(t)\,\mathrm dt\\&=2\int_0^xh(t)\,\mathrm dt-\int_0^xg'(t)\,\mathrm dt\\&=2\int_0^xh(t)\,\mathrm dt-g(x).\end{align}So, $F$ is the difference between two differentiable functions, and therefore it is differentiable.

Comment: It would be nice if *occasionally* you would give the OP a chance to think about the hint without immediately posting the complete answer.

Comment: No problems I read the answer line by line and try to solve it with reading one line and using it as a hint.